# Sql Time Conversion to UTC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to write a SQL Stored Procedure which returns UTC time when we give a date and time along with another time zone.

for e.g. I will give input as @TimeZone='IST and @Time='2018-06-18 17:08:31.383' and I expect the UTC time as output which is '2018-06-18 11:38:31.383'

I already have this statement ,

```
DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), @Time)
```

but this needs to run on different Servers to return different UTC's .Is there any possibility to obtain this in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Use the `datetimeoffset` datatype. [datetimeoffset (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

SQL server does not know what IST is. Also, some time zones use daylight saving which makes this even more complicated (daylight savings change for different locations on different days) . You might be able to use a table with timezones and differencefromutc columns , but that would be quite difficult to achieve.

Looking at this a bit more, if you are on SQL 2017, [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: This isn't really true, as of SQL Server 2008, the data type `datetimeoffset` has been available, which (according to the documentation) is described as: *"Defines a date that is combined with a time of a day that **has time zone awareness** and is based on a 24-hour clock."*

Comment: The OP does not say he has the data stored in UTC, or that he has the offset stored in a table. Datatype datetimeoffset can only be populated using a static value using sysdatetimeoffset or using the function ToDateTimeOffset

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a datetime expressed as non UTC to its UTC value you can use dateadd within a case construct.

```
CASE 
  WHEN @TimeZone='IST' THEN DATEADD(mi, 330, @time) 
  WHEN @TimeZone='GMT-1' THEN DATEADD(mi, -60, @time) 
......
......
ELSE @time END
```

Indeed there is no different UTC's, since UTC it is the universal time referred to the time on greenwich timezone it is only one.